# return result from memcached.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memcached

I am using npm memcached package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached

It is possible to return data from memcached get method? 
Now return data is undefined/

```
memcached.set('foo', 'bar', 10, function (err) { });

let data1;
memcached.get('foo', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data); // bar
    data1 = data
});
console.log(data1); // undefined

let data2 = memcached.get('foo', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data); // undefined
    return data;
});
console.log(data2); // undefined


let data3 = async () => {
    let result = await memcached.get('foo', function (err, data) {
        console.log(data); // bar
    });
    console.log(result); // undefined
    return result;
}
console.log(data); // {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't return from **get()** as it's an asynchronous callback. What you can do is:

with callbacks:

```
memcached.get('foo',(err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('data: ', data);
  }
});
```

with promises:

```
memcached.get('foo')
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    });
```

and with async/await:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await memcached.get('foo');
        console.log('data: ', data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    }
}
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed Amir Ansari, but unfortunately these methods do not work. `with callbacks:` get value, but it is default behavior in this method (I need to return value to variable, to check it after). `with promises:` get `"Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"`  `error`. With `with async/await:` get `'data: ' undefined`

Comment: May be **get()** is not supported by promises.Can you try like this:

const { promisify } = require('util');

const getData = async () => {
    try {
     const getDataPromise = promisify(memcached.get);
        const data = await getDataPromise('foo');
        console.log('data: ', data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    }
}

Comment: Yes, Mohammed. you are right. memcached methods is not supported by promises. I trying you advice, but have memcached.js error . `Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined` . I trying with other not supported promises functions and it's work! And finally me responded memcached package developers [ https://github.com/3rd-Eden/memcached/issues/350 ]. So there is additional memcached-promisify packege that solved that issue. Thanks for you help. Unfortunately I can not mark your answer is usefull(( because my reputation is less than need

Comment: memcached.js error . `Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined`  was from this line of code ` memcached.get = function get(key, callback) {
    var fullkey = this.namespace + key; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since memcached is async you can't really return from it, altho I see OP found a way via a promisify wrapper. What you can do is call another function from inside the callback.
Working with async socket communication I've had to split up a lot of my workflows into request and receives.

```
memcached.get('foo',(err, data) => {
  doStuff(data);
});

function doStuff(data) {
//do some stuff here
}
```

Of course you could always do your work with the data inside the handler too. But in some cases that isnt the best approach.